# Handling floats in redis

Tags: lua, redis

I need to use Redis in a project I am using and was wondering if there was anyway to do proper mathmatic operations and comparisons on floats using LUA scripts(or anyway really).  For example, I have a field, and need to multiply it by another field, and compare it to a third field. For example

```
local staticVal = .2
local dynamicVal2 = redis.pcall('GET', 'dynamicVal2')
local calcVal = dynamicVal * staticVal
local compareVal = 100
if calcVal < compareVal then
   return false
else
   return true
```

Is there a possible way to do this, or do I have to just make the GET calls from another language and do the comparison there?

Thank you

Edit:

Or the ability to just compare floating point numbers would be helpful.  It seems that a dictionary comparison is done rather than a numerical comparison.

Edit 2:

```
SET val1 10.5
SET val2 3.5
EVAL "local val1 = redis.pcall('GET','val1'); local val2 = redis.pcall('GET','val2');  if val1 > val2 then  return val1 else    return val2 end" 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can: in Lua, all the numbers are floats. It is actually more difficult to work with large integer values than with floats (due to the internal numbers representation).

From redis-cli:

```
set dynamicVal2 100000.0
eval "local staticVal = .2 ; local dynamicVal = tonumber(redis.call('GET', 'dynamicVal2')); local calcVal = dynamicVal * staticVal; local compareVal = 100; if calcVal < compareVal then return false; else return true; end;" 0
(integer) 1
```

Now using Lua for the example you gave is not that useful: what is done with Lua on server-side could be easily done on client-side with similar efficiency. And it is actually better to do it on client-side if you can. Like with many other data stores, the more you can do on client-side for the same number of roundtrips, the best it is.

It would have been more useful if the Lua script was effectively used to avoid multiple roundtrips to Redis.

Comment: I have a question then, take a look at my edit 2.  Why does the function return 3.5 instead of 10.5.  It seems to me like it is doing a dictionary comparison(comparing the 3 to 1 and returning the greater of the two) instead of comparing 3.5 to 10.5.

Comment: Use local var1 = tonumber( redis.call("GET",'val1')); to convert the string in float.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that a dictionary comparison is done rather than a numerical comparison.
>
> ```
> local val1 = redis.pcall('GET','val1'); 
> local val2 = redis.pcall('GET','val2');
> if val1 > val2 then  ...
> ```

Check the type of `val1` and `val2` (e.g. `print(type(val1))`). My guess is that they are strings, which is why you're getting a lexical comparison rather than a numerical one.

Lua's native number type is floating point and it has no problem comparing them. If your values are indeed strings, you just need to convert them into numbers (e.g. `tonumber(val1)`) before comparing them.

Comment: I see this now, I think I was getting confused when I converted it to a number, and returned the number, Redis converted it to an int.  I confused myself thinking all of the calculations were done as ints.  My problem was I did not reconvert it to a string for Redis.  Thanks for pointing that out.